# how to parse this in android studio with json

Tags: android, json

how to parse this in android studio with json. Iget this result but I dont understand how to parse it

```
{
        "status": "OK",
        "data": {
            "name": "RR",
            "logo": "http:\/\/www.sdfs.win\/images\/logos\/rr.png"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also use Gson to directly map your json on your models..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
    String status=obj.getString("status");
    JSONObject data_obj=obj.getJSONObject("data");
    String name=data_obj.getString("name");
    String logo=data_obj.getString("logo");
```

set value

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();

    PrefsEditor.putString("name", name);
    PrefsEditor.putString("logo", logo);
```

get value

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();

    String name_value=preferences.getString("name", "");    
    String logo_value=preferences.getString("logo", "");
```

Comment: should I use try/catch method

Comment: how I can return this 2 string can you help?

Comment: you can not return these 2 values at time..Store into SharedPreferences and then use where you want to use